# How to apply different stylesheets based on user on wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, stylesheet

I have a Wordpress self-hosted website for extra content about a series of books. On the near future, I intend to let the user declare which book(s) from the series he/she has read - and whilst it would be just for fun, I thought I could take this idea further.

The thing is, since some content on generic pages might be considered spoilers if they haven't read some of the books, I would like to apply a different stylesheet based on logged in user - so if the user has read up until book 2, a stylesheet would be loaded in such a way that any paragraph with the class "book3" or higher would be automatically converted into a hidden paragraph with a spoiler alert. But if the user *has* already read book 3, a different stylesheet would be loaded; one that wouldn't do that, and would let the user see the content normally.

I reckon this could also be done with javascript, but I suppose CSS would be easier? I'd be up for answers based on both methods, of course (including jQuery regarding javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this without javascript.

One way to do this would be to add an additional class to the body if a user has read a particular book. For example, if a user has read book 1 you would want to add the class 'read-book-1' to the body. You can accomplish this in WordPress using the `body_class` filter.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/body_class

Here is a stripped down example:

```
add_filter('body_class', function($classes) {
    if(/* if user has read book 1 */) {
        $classes[] = 'read-book-1';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Then, assuming your markup looks like this:

```
<p class="spoiler book-1">...</p>
```

You could override your spoiler style if the user has read book 1:

```
p.spoiler {
    visibility:hidden;
}

.read-book-1 p.spoiler.book-1 {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Note that I'm just assuming you're using `visibility: hidden;` to hide spoiler text. There is more than one way to do this.

If you wanted to incorporate additional features, such as a link to reveal spoiler text, then you would need javascript. If you just wanted to reveal spoiler text on hover you can do it with just css:

```
p.spoiler:hover {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Comment: The interesting part is getting the information that the user has read the book. I'm thinking about this tutorial ( http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields ) for creation of relevant user fields, and then using `get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'booksread', 'book-1')` in place of the commented `if user has read book 1` in your example. Would that be ideal?

Answer (score 1):

To load a different CSS file according to a Javascript variable you can use a [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement. Each case would use [document.write()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) to write in the . This needs to be done before the body of the HTML loads so you don't overwrite anything. The MDN page which is linked to explains the details for this.

```
switch (variable) {
  case possibility1:
    document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='___.css' type='text/css'>");
    break;

  case possibility2: ...

  default: ...
}
```

Another alternative could be applying a class to spoilers. If content would be spoiled for book 2 and you know book2.hasRead === false, the hidden class would be applied to that content. Using [element.classlist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) is the easiest way that comes to mind.

Using a similar method to how responsive design uses different CSS for different situations could work as well but I don't know enough about that to advise how to do so.